# Не работает макрос в ms office 2013

Tags: vba

Вот такой код:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
        E
End Sub
Sub AutoOpen()
        E
End Sub
Sub Document_Open()
        E
End Sub
Public Function E() As Variant
        Application.Quit
End Function
```

У меня активированный 2013 office word, но почему не работает этот код? При открытии документа появляться кнопка "enable content" после нажатия ничего не происходит.

Comment: Укажите используемое приложение MS Office. *почему не работает этот код?* А чему тут работать? Если приложение - Excel, код расположен в common-модуле, и макросы разрешены - при попытке открытия приложение тут же закроется.

Comment: Указал, в том то и проблема что не закрывается.

Comment: Подробно. 1) Приложение - Excel? да или нет? 2) Код - в common-модуле? да или нет? 3) Настройки безопасности - какие? 4) Поставь в КАЖДОЙ процедуре первым оператор `Stop` - при открытии книги останов кода происходит? если да - где именно? 5) Почему две процедуры AutoOpen()?

Comment: Спасибо,  разобрался, настройки безопасности и две процедуры AutoOpen().